# Custom format for SAS

Tags: sas, format

Hi I'm interested in making a couple of slightly complex custom formats for data I produce in SAS. I need it to be of the numeric type.

FORMAT 1

```
0="-"
>0="<number>%"
<0="<number>%"
```

ie

```
0 >>>>>>> -
.74 >>>>> 74%
-.65>>>>> -65%
```

FORMAT 2

```
0="-"
>0="$<number(with commas)>"
<0="$(<number(with commas)>"
```

ie

```
0>>>>>>-
1467>>>>$1,467
-39087>>$(39,087)
```

I've made simple custom formats using code like this

```
proc format;
picture test
    0='-';
run;
```

But I'm not sure how to write the syntax to append the `$` sign and `(` `)` signs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The percent format is fairly straightforward.  The dollar one is a mite trickier as you have to watch your widths.

Basically you need to use `prefix` to get anything on the front (dollar, paren, minus sign) and just put anything that you want at the end actually at the end.  '0' means a sometimes-printing digit, '9' means always-printing digit.

You use `mult` to make the .13 -> 13%.

And, for dollar, you can make use of the `dollar` format.  You might also be able to use the `NEGPAREN` format on the negative side, but you can't combine that with the dollar sign...

```
proc format;
picture pctfmt 
    low - <0= '000%' (mult=100 prefix='-')
    0       = '-'
    0<-high = '000%' (mult=100);
picture dollfmt
    low - <0  = '000,000,000.00)' (prefix='$(')
    0         = '-'
    0 <- high = [dollar16.2]
  ; 

run;

data _null_;
input x;
put x= pctfmt.;
datalines;
-.15
-.05
0
.05
.15
;;;;
run;


data _null_;
input x;
put x= dollfmt12.2;
datalines;
-5.93
-13432554
0
12345324
5.98
;;;;
run;
```

Comment: This is great. How does the ` low - <0  = '000,000,000.00)' (prefix='$(')` line work? What do all those zeros represent? Thanks!

Comment: `0` are digit selectors.  `0` means `optional print` while a nonzero (I use 9) means `mandatory print` (so like `w.d` vs `Zw.d` format).  You could also use the `dig3sep` option to specify the commas, but I find it easy to read this way with the prefix (since you cannot use the shortcut format).

Comment: is there a way to round in a particular style? I'm finding any number less than .01 and greater than 0, and any number greater than -.01 and less than zero, becomes a blank space as opposed to a 0 (resulting in "-"). I've found a way to hack around it but it is burdensome and inefficient.

Comment: Picture formats have rounding options, but it's just round or (not round).  You can either change the `0` line to be `-.01 <-> .01` or similar, or add the `round` option to the picture, to tell it to round the value.